# Jquery - Update content with ajax (Chat)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing a minichat and am using a code to read the messages and update a div with ajax, you're just not working right scroll bar, when she gets Bugando starts, does anyone know how to improve this' code?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

loadXMLDoc1();

});
</script>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc1() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'miniforum_msgs.php',
        success: function(result) {
            $("#result777").html(result);
            $("#result777").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);  
            setTimeout(loadXMLDoc1, 1000);
        }
    });
};
</script>

<div id="publicidade2">
<div id="result777">
```

Comment: Websockets are in a way the opposite of an ajax request. Instead of your 200 users requesting data from your server every second, your server will send data to your 200 users only when new data is available.

Comment: There are nothing but benefits. You're users will get the data faster, you will use less of the user's resources, and you will use less of your server's resources.